# How to get p4merge to come up when I do git mergetool?

Tags: git, macos

I did setup p4merge using this in my .gitconfig:

```
[merge]
    tool = p4mergetool
    stat = true
[mergetool "p4mergetool"]
    cmd = /Applications/p4merge.app/Contents/Resources/launchp4merge "$BASE" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"
    keepBackup = false
    keepTemporaries = false
    trustExitCode = false
    prompt = false
[diff]
    tool = p4mergetool
    renames = copies
    mnemonicprefix = true
[difftool "p4mergetool"]
    cmd = /Applications/p4merge.app/Contents/Resources/launchp4merge "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
    keepBackup = false
    keepTemporaries = false
    trustExitCode = false
    prompt = false
```

When I try to git mergetool in my project it can find the conflicted files and open p4merge tool but it open to choose the files, not with the conflicted file opened. How to solve this?

My versions:
Git 2.23.
Latest p4merge version P4Merge/MACOSX1015X86_64/2020.2/1999419.
macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: Could you run git status to find if there _are_ any conflicts at all ?

Comment: Yes there some conflicts and git automatically open p4merge but it does not open the conflicted file, it open a window that I have to choose the files to merge.

Answer (score 2):

I just solved it! The definitions of `cmd` should be

```
cmd = /Applications/p4merge.app/Contents/MacOS/p4merge "$BASE" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"
...
cmd = /Applications/p4merge.app/Contents/MacOS/p4merge "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
```

Comment: Thank you for edit, just corrected it to p4merge instead of lauchp4merge!